# How to get Bootstrap 3 Datepicker display in this picture?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've got display problem when using http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker in Bootstrap 3.
[image]
How to get datepicker in this picture?
[image]

I'm using MVC 5 with auto generated views
Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TerminateDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group date" id="dp3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TerminateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TerminateDate)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
Now it looks like better but a little long, how to set the length? 
[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TerminateDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group date">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TerminateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TerminateDate)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your question? *"How to get datepicker in this picture?"* isn't a valid sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps. I just added some class and change some tag. It will look like [this](http://www.bootply.com/130408)

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TerminateDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="input-group col-md-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-group date" id="dp3">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TerminateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @readonly = "readonly" } })
      <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TerminateDate)
  </div>
</div>
```

Update:Take a look at the "Column sizing" subsection [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)

Comment: I updated the question, it almost done, this is inspired by your code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this format:

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
        </i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default site.css created when you make a new project has a max-width set on the input element:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Remove or comment this out and your col-md-10 will work perfect.