# MVC5 Adding glyphicon next to EditorFor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

This is driving me a bit crazy adjusting the desired width to the glyphicon I have added next to a EditorFor textbox.

I have the below which I added a glyphicon next to the EditorFor, notice I initially put `.col-md-10` which is the default generated by MVC5 View template:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 input-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactedDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it looks like this, notice the glyphicon is so far away:

[image]

I later change the `.col-md-10` to `.col-md-4` which become the below:

[image]

Still some distance away and when I use `.col-md-3`, it will overlap with the box:

[image]

What's more is when I adjust the width of the browser, the glyphicon will just moves to the position like the 1st screenshot when I use `.col-md-4` or `.col-md-3`, it's like it does not stick just next to the textbox.

I have also checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100880/how-to-get-bootstrap-3-datepicker-display-in-this-picture) here but it does not help me.

How do I add the glyphicon properly?

Comment: Are you using the default ASP.NET MVC project template? It has a CSS rule that causes this issue.

Comment: Yes I am and I cannot figure out which one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tasos, your comment has just given me an idea to google on the net and I have found it here: https://roastlambda.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/fixing-wayward-input-groups-in-the-default-mvc5-bootstrap-template/

Comment: Hehe, just posted an answer about that! Check also a fix for a similar issue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new ASP.NET MVC project comes with a `Site.css` stylesheet. The rule that causes the issue is the one below that makes all `<input>` have a `max-width:280` and that messes up your `.input-group`:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

You can change the above rule to include the `.input-group` and have the following:

```
input,
select,
textarea, 
.input-group {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

**Edit**: This CSS also breaks the `.form-block` class of Bootstrap, so you will need the following rule as well.

```
input.form-block,
select.form-block,
textarea.form-block {
max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: I just found out the best to to separate .input-group like this .input-group {
    max-width: 350px;
} this will allow the width of the textbox to be consistent with the rest of the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

no CS needed. here is part of the code from my project

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.scheduledDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div  class='input-group date' id='myDatepicker'>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.scheduledDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.scheduledDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

and to regulate dates to only after what the time and date is now

```
<script>
$('#myDatepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
    minDate: 'now'
});</script>
```